# Putting HTML in JSON

Tags: php, html, json

As per title, is it considered a good practice to put HTML in JSON? The reason I need to do this is because I would like to have a custom dropdown where the list is coming from the user input, and the json looks like so:

```
{ listTitle: 'Tasks', listHtml: '<ul><li></li>...</ul>' }
```

and I have the foreach as following (keep in mind this is a stripped down version of my code, validation is in place, but for the sake of this question I took them out)

```
$list = /** Code to grab 'Tasks' list and its title from mysql **/;
$title = 'Tasks';
$listHtml = '';
foreach($list as $content) { $listHtml .= '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</li>'; }

exit(json_encode(array(
   'title' => $title, 'listHtml' => '<ul>' . $listHtml . '</ul>'
)));
```

My worry is that there might be some special characters that might break the JSON String. Please help.

Comment: It's just a string. Strings are supported in JSON. Even those with HTML in it ;) - see http://json.org/

Comment: @andreas: separation of presentation from data seems to be the main point of formats like JSON.  Do you intend to let other websites or users fetch this data on the side and use it _outside_ of your website?  If so, adding in html will ruin that.  If not, if this is a json feed you use only to help build your webpages, then it would be up to you.

Comment: @bob Eh? I thought cross domain policy is in place for things like you mentioned? So unless I willingly write callback support on the script, I should be ok? Please enlighten me

Comment: @andreas: cross-domain policy only affects the use of `XMLHttpRequest` and similar objects on your own website, not the actual source of your json feed/string.  Different things.  If your server is internet-facing, and unless protected by server settings or user access control, your json feed is open to the public.  Do you prefer that external users have freedom to use this feed as they wish?  Or do you prefer it just be used to only help dynamically build your own website?

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense. But this is a generated user list, so there's session checking on the server to see if the user is logged in. Thanks for the insight :)

Comment: @andreas: Sorry, I may be a little confusing, but nothing to do with permissions in this case.  The consideration is if you want others to reuse this JSON feed of your's. For example, I have my own website (say geared towards town residents), and you have your website (say you're the weather channel).  Your JSON feed provides local weather, and I want to reuse that data on my own website.  Assuming you permitted me to do so, I can't use JSON text preformatted with HTML for my own website.  If you want to provide that service, then best avoid preformatting with html.  Otherwise, not important.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You wouldn't be the first to do it, and certainly not the last.

To really answer the question, assuming you're following the protocol/standard and not breaking it (including quotes in the string without escaping them, for instance) you should be fine. json_encode does a great job at all this, but as @Kolink mentioned make sure you encode it to UTF8 first otherwise stray Unicode characters will occasionally break it resulting in empty output.

Beyond that, it's programmer preference to use it. Some avoid it and keep the UI work on the page, others have the server generate the UI and let JavaScript just dump it--either way it's your call, and perfectly acceptable.

Comment: As a follow-up, libraries like [Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com/) allow very easy convergence of JSON data and UI integration using an easy-to-use templating system.

Answer (score 11):

There's nothing wrong with it. `json_encode` escapes all characters anyway, so the only thing you have to beware of is make sure your strings are `utf8_encode`d.

Answer (score 0):

You could, sure, but you could just as easily pass the values as an array in the JSON and put the HTML rendering code in the client; saving you server cycles, bandwidth bytes, and logic-presentation blending.