# json_encode not working with a html string as value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am debugging this ajax for quite a time now. I have this on my jQUery file:

```
$("#typeForm").ajaxForm({
    success : function(html){
        alert(html);
}).submit();
```

This calls **service.php**, and within it I have this:

```
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$str = "<div style='position:relative'><img src='/assets/ui/success.png' /><span style='position:relative;top:-15px;'>Nachricht empfangen!</span></div>";
echo json_encode(array('file_name' => $data['upload_data']['file_name'], 'prompt' => $str));
```

This won't work. But by replacing `$str` to `$str = "HELLO WORLD";` the jQuery alerts what should I expected. What seems to be the problem?

EDIT:

Here is a screenie of the output:

[image]

It does alerts, but if I modify my jQuery into this:

```
$("#typeForm").ajaxForm({
    success : function(html){
        var obj = $.parseJSON(html);
        alert(obj);
}).submit();
```

Then it does nothing at all, even alerting.

I did a var_dump on the `json_encode` and here is the dump, it looks like a malformed JSON:

```
string(214) "{"file_name":"cde595988d386529909ce5a8fe3a6d6f.png","prompt":"<div style="position:relative;"><img src="\/assets\/ui\/success.png" \=""><span style="position:relative;top:-15px;">Nachricht empfangen!&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/div&gt;"}"
</span></div>
```

Here is the full content of **service.php**

```
class Service extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $filename = 'uploadfile';

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/temp';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|doc|docx|pdf|ppt|pptx|xls|xlsx|bmp';
        $config['max_size'] = '3072';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($filename))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    echo json_encode(array('error' => $error['error']));
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $file_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
            //print_r($data);
            //echo json_encode(array('test' => "Hello World"));
            $str = "<div style='position:relative;'><img src='/assets/ui/success.png' /><span style='position:relative;top:-15px;'>Nachricht empfangen!</span></div>";
            $str2 = json_encode(array("file_name" => $file_name, "prompt" => $str));
            //var_dump($str2);
            exit(json_encode(array('file_name' => $data['upload_data']['file_name'], 'prompt' => $str)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON looks like...?

Comment: by "won't work" do you mean it's throwing errors? Or it doesn't inject the HTML or..?

Comment: How does it 'not work'? JSON couldn't care less WHAT you're embedding within the string - it can be numbers, it can be text, it can be html. it doesn't matter, as long the JSON syntax rules are honored.

Comment: guys, see my edited post. sorry for not posting the output.

Comment: So it alerts... ? Please specify exactly what your problem is and/or the expected behavior... Your question as of now is very vague.

Comment: yes it does but if i replace the alert with `var obj = $.parseJSON(html); alert(obj);` then it now does nothing at all.

Answer (score 112):

I was having same problem with `json_encode` today. But after testing a lot I found the correct solution:

In PHP to encode the array or string:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

In JS to decode the same:

```
var d = $.parseJSON(content);
```

Comment: I was having the same issue but I was almost to the solution. I was using `json_encode($json, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS)`. Changing the `JSON_HEX_APOS` to `JSON_HEX_TAG` made my problems disappear!

Comment: `{"link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/YXNpZADpBWEdrUlJiUzc0SWFWZATI4SEVJUmJHTTJQVHU2M3owcTJLOHh5MnJYOTI0LWdMT3VFUC1veXNWdXBhM3o3RzdkQmV4cjNfTC1nSkdheGFhV19pWWU5T1ZAWSzlkN0NBTUl4NVZAKTE9oRjlFbjdObU5i\/","id":"1686741234967769"}1`   I have this html coming from facebook, I tried converting that into JSON but its not working..   I did like this..  `$request = json_encode($json, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);`   Please help

Comment: This helped me a lot. One comment: if your response has several components you must parse the whole response first, before splitting the components. Parsing just the html portion didn't work properly.

Comment: Important: With `json_encode()` (without paramaters) you get an object returned that you can access with `$obj->attributes`. Using the parameters above, it seems that the object is turned into an array, accessible by `$obj['attributes']`.

Answer (score 10):

How about convert all the potential problem characters instead of just what fixes the problem in this circumstance:

```
die(json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Comment: This works great! I was encoding to base64 when I needed to send some html in a JSON response which worked fine until trying to send emojis. Now using the flags above everything works great without needing to encode then decode base64.

Comment: This should be top / accepted answer as it solves this problem and any future encoding issues with possible content.  Best & most robust solution.

Answer (score 3):

Some stuff to try:

ajaxForm supports dataType argument, if you expect a JSON coming from the server, use `dataType: json` like so

```
$("#typeForm").ajaxForm({
    success : function(html){
       // html here is already automatically a json object
       alert(html.prompt);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
}).submit();
```

Could you post the full service.php? OR try the following:

> exit(json_encode(array('file_name' =>
>   $data['upload_data']['file_name'], 'prompt' => $str)));

-- EDIT --

Not sure why json_encode returns such weird string :s, is the `json_encode` a standard php library or an external library? I'm asking this because some servers don't have json_encode in their php installation... I tested on my local and using php internal json_encode and it works fine:

```
<?php
$str = "<div style='position:relative'><img src='/assets/ui/success.png' /><span style='position:relative;top:-15px;'>Nachricht empfangen!</span></div>";
echo json_encode(array('prompt' => $str));

// output
//{"prompt":"<div style='position:relative'><img src='\/assets\/ui\/success.png' \/><span style='position:relative;top:-15px;'>Nachricht empfangen!<\/span><\/div>"}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but no it doesn't work. If I did this, then it won't alert at all.

Comment: Do you have a test page on this? Easier if I could go through and test directly

Comment: and yes it won't alert as dataType json would expect a valid json string, in which case "HELLO WORLD" isn't a valid json

Comment: thanks, but none i don't have a test page for this. it's set on my local. I guess this concerns a malformed JSON because if I var_dump the json_encode it looks like a well-malformed JSON.

Comment: If you are using chrome browser, press F12 and look on the bottom right corner, if you see something like `(x) 1`, it might tell you. json_encode should properly escape your HTML, so don't worry too much about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492916/putting-html-in-json

Comment: edited my answer... it seems your service.php has extra markup towards the end of the script

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot find a better solution for this you can encode the value to base64 encoding:

```
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$str = base64_encode("<div style='position:relative'><img src='/assets/ui/success.png' /><span style='position:relative;top:-15px;'>Nachricht empfangen!</span></div>");
echo json_encode(array('file_name' => $data['upload_data']['file_name'], 'prompt' => $str));
```

and in the client decode it, IMO this is more safer this is also more applicable if you're processing characters from different languages.

ALSO:

to sure that no other characters will be added on the json string call **exit;** writer after you print it.

Comment: for chrome or mozilla you can use atob() or btoa()

Comment: for other browsers u can use this js library http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/base64-encoder-decoder-with-javascript.html or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript

Comment: this is good idea, base64 encode on php side and base64 decode on js side.

Comment: I really prefer this approach because you don't have to mess with any json_encode flags!

Comment: I was using base64 until I had trouble with emojis not rendering, then I switched to `json_encode` with all the flags and it solved all my problems!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to escape your quotes server-side.  Since they are in there, it seems to be creating an invalid JSON string.

Comment: Just what I am suspecting to, but I can't seem to find what's the proper escaping should I do in `$str`

Comment: if you want to manually escape this, you could change to this

$str = "<div style=\'position:relative;\'><img src=\'/assets/ui/success.png\' /><span style=\'position:relative;top:-15px;\'>Nachricht empfangen!</span></div>";

Answer (score 0):

```
string(214) "{"file_name":"cde595988d386529909ce5a8fe3a6d6f.png","prompt":"<div style="position:relative;"><img src="\/assets\/ui\/success.png" \=""><span style="position:relative;top:-15px;">Nachricht empfangen!&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/div&gt;"}"
</span></div>
```

This seems to be broken because there's no quote escaping. When an unescaped " is found, it breaks the JSON structure you expect.
Escaped " should be \", single quotes with \' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should call only `prompt` object of your array not all! like below:

```
$("#typeForm").ajaxForm({
    success : function(html){
        var obj = $.parseJSON(html);
        alert(obj.prompt);
}).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't play well with `string` output that comes out of magic method `__toString()` - it nearly impossible to `json_encode()` anything that even remotely touched something like this.

```
<?php
/**
 * DEBUGGING NIGHTMARE
 * SO MUCH FUN, 10/10,
 */
class Nightmare {
  protected $str;
  public function __construct($str) {
    $this->str = $str;
  }
  public function __toString() {
    return $this->str;
  }
}

$test = new Nightmare('Hello Friends.');
echo $test;
> Hello Friends.

// cooool, so let's JSON the hell out of it, EASY

echo json_encode(['our_hello' => $test]);
// This what you expect to get, right?
> {"our_hello":"Hello Friends."}

// HAHA NO!!!
// THIS IS WHAT YOU GET:
> {"our_hello":{}}


// and this is why is that:

var_dump($test);
object(Nightmare)#1 (1) {
  ["str":protected]=>
  string(14) "Hello Friends."
}

print_r($test);
Nightmare Object
(
    [str:protected] => Hello Friends.
)
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow strives to be a professional knowledge base. Jokes and inappropriate language have no place here

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating in a humorous way the problem you encountered.  Keep up the good work!