# Jquery for submiting without refresh (no validation required)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty

I have a form for Tags that is working OK, with some server validation, I would like to add a Jquery to submit the content without refreshing:

```
<form method="post" action="tags">
  <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="getId()" />
        <input type="text" name="tag" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" name="add" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/).  Using it, you can submit a form without reloading the page like so:

```
<form id="aForm" action="target.php" method="post>
    ...
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#aForm").ajaxForm();
    });
</script>
```

The `ajaxForm()` function also supports all options (such as a callback function) that can be passed to the standard [jQuery $.ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#toptions) function.

Comment: Thanks Vulcan! I tried your answer but it's refreshing. The form plug in is installed, the id form is aForm as yours. What could it be?

Comment: @82din I can't say for sure without seeing your code.  Try replicating what the form's tutorial has, and debugging (with some web console) to make sure that it's actually recognizing the plugin's functions.

Comment: I had a conflict with the $ symbol. I used jQuery instead. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you also can get data in return,
$('#form_id').ajaxForm(function(data){
            if(data === '1'){}
}

Comment: you also can get value in return,
`$('#form_id').ajaxForm(function(data){
            alert(data);
});`

to get multiple values use **JSON** encode in php, for more reference visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764598/json-encode-not-working-with-a-html-string-as-value)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(form).submit( function() { // could use $(#submit).on('click', function(){ as well
   $.ajax({
     url: 'yourposturl',
     data: $(form).serialize(),
     Success: function() {
         alert('ok');
     }
   }); //end ajax   

  return false;
   }); //end submit()
 });
```

Should take all form vars , serialize them so the server can receive, the return false is so page doesnt refresh on submit (stops propagation and default)

Comment: Thanks worthy, I used your function inside the document ready, with the proper url and it still refresh. I don't get the OK message.

Comment: Whoops, had a syntax error there, try this, fully tested with doc ready function

Answer (score 0):

Add the JQuery javascript library

Turn the submit into a button

```
 <button id="submitbutton" >Add</button>
```

Add ids to your inputs

```
<input type="text" id="tag" name="tag" />
```

And add the jquery to the click for the button ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#submitbutton").button().click(function(){
     $.post("tags.php",{id: $("#id").val(), tag: $("#tag").val()});
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="tags">
  <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="getId()" />
        <input type="text" name="tag" />
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Add" name="add" />
    </div>
</form>


$(function(){
   $('.button').click(function(){
       var data = $('form').serializeToObject();
       $.post('tags.php', data);
   });
});

// jQuery Extension to serialize a selector's elements to an object
$.fn.serializeToObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();

    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Gabe! I used your solution but it doesn't submit. I checked the url inside the $.post and is the same than the action form.