# json_encode() can't return html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to return some code snippets from php to jquery. Everything works ok, but when I try to return html with `<body>` and `<html>` tags then I get my javascript code in output (raw code)

this is my code:

```
$snippetData['snippetId'][] = $snippetId;
$snippetData['title'][] = $title;
$snippetData['description'][] = $description;
$snippetData['snippet'][] = $code;
echo json_encode($snippetData);
```

EDIT:

To make it more clear this is what I store in this array:

```
snippedId = 5 (integer value)
title = 'some title'  (string value)
description 'some description' (string value)
snippet = '<html> <body> <title>some title </title> </body> </html>' (string value)
```

Comment: Can you show us what this script echos?  Where and how are you using the echoed values?  I see nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: It is valid JSON, and not just *real* HTML you're trying to parse ?

Comment: Where is your sample `$snippetData`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7DJanGJE this is output

Comment: $snippetData contains just dummy data, for testing. And in 'code' part it contains simple html with body, title and one dummy label.

Comment: Your `"` from the code are not escaped. Nor your `/`.

Comment: @Alen: Is that *exactly* what was generated by this script?  Or did you modify it in any way?  That JSON is invalid, and I've *never* seen `json_encode` generate invalid JSON.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, this is exactly what was generated, I copied complete output

Comment: How is the snippet `$code` generated? Is this some html/js code you wrote yourself?

Comment: @tenub I get $code from database

Comment: @Alen: What are you doing with this JSON?  How are you using it?

Comment: Actually, you are not storing what you say. For example, snippetId contains an array of a single integer, not an integer value. You are making an array of arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```php
<?php echo json_encode($snippetData, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764598/json-encode-not-working-with-a-html-string-as-value)

Comment: This escapes html, but when I try to decode it in jquery I get this (this wierd code is generated in place where normally should be head tag): http://pastebin.com/05K1yx3w

Answer (score 1):

seems something is wrong with " char. try escaping them or base64 encode on html in json,

after getting data you can decode it.

ie you'll have:

```
JzxodG1sPiA8Ym9keT4gPHRpdGxlPnNvbWUgdGl0bGUgPC90aXRsZT4gPC9ib2R5PiA8L2h0bWw+Jw==
```

instead of

```
'<html> <body> <title>some title </title> </body> </html>'
```

when you decode, you'll get your snippet back