# Ajax + Datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Ajax. And I don't really have much experience with js either, but I need to get this done and it's driving me crazy.

So I have the following html in my view (I don't think it's relevant, but I'm building an app using codeigniter...

```
<div id="tabsl">
 <div class="portlet-body" >
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" id="sample_2">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>
           </th>
           <th class="all">Name</th>
           <th class="min-phone-l">Calls</th>
           <th class="min-phone-1">Walk Ins</th>
           <th class="desktop">Total Prospects</th>
           <th class="desktop">Appointmets Booked</th>
           <th class="min-tablet">Completed Presentations</th>
           <th class="all">CLOSED SALES</th>
           <th class="all">Closed Sales RATIO</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody >
        <?php foreach ($columns as $record): ?>
           <tr>
              <td>

              </td>
              <td><?php echo $record->name ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $record->calls ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $record->walkins ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $record->tprospects ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $record->appointments ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $record->presentations ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $record->sales ?></td>
              <td>
              <?php if ($record->presentations != 0) {
                 echo ($record->sales / $record->presentations)*100 . " %";
              } else {
                 echo "0 %";
              } ?>

              </td>
           </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

The table is responsive, hiding columns according to screen size and generating a button to show the hidden columns underneath the rows, like this:

[image: responsive table]

Then the user is able to select a date range. That's when I make the following ajax call...

```
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {

   var dStart =  $('#dStart').val();
   var dEnd   =  $('#dEnd').val();

   $.post("<?php echo base_url('index.php/Ajax/ajax_get_data') ?>", {dStart : dStart, dEnd : dEnd}, function(data){

      $('#tabsl').html(data.content);
   }, "json");              

});
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public function ajax_get_data() {

    $startDate = $this->input->post('dStart');
    $endDate   = $this->input->post('dEnd');

    $report = $this->Reports_model->the_report($startDate, $endDate);

    if ($report->num_rows() > 0) {

        $report_html = '<div class="portlet-body" >
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" id="sample_2">
                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                        <th>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="all">Name</th>
                                        <th class="min-phone-l">Calls</th>
                                        <th class="min-phone-1">Walk Ins</th>
                                        <th class="desktop">Total Prospects</th>
                                        <th class="desktop">Appointmets Booked</th>
                                        <th class="min-tablet">Completed Presentations</th>
                                        <th class="all">CLOSED SALES</th>
                                        <th class="all">Closed Sales RATIO</th>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody >';

        foreach ($report->result() as $key) {

            $report_html .= '<tr><td></td>';
            $report_html .= '<td>' . $key->name . '</td>';
            $report_html .= '<td>' . $key->calls . '</td>';
            $report_html .= '<td>' . $key->walkins . '</td>';
            $report_html .= '<td>' . $key->tprospects . '</td>';
            $report_html .= '<td>' . $key->appointments . '</td>';
            $report_html .= '<td>' . $key->presentations . '</td>';
            $report_html .= '<td>' . $key->sales . '</td>';
            $report_html .= '<td>' . $key->sales . '</td>';
            $report_html .= '</tr>';
        }

            $report_html .= '   </tbody></table></div>';

        $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $report_html);

        echo json_encode($result);

    } else {

        echo "nope";

    }

}
```

And finally, the scrip that relates to that id="sample_2"

```
var TableDatatablesResponsive = function () {


            var initTable2 = function () {
                var table = $('#sample_2');

                var oTable = table.dataTable({
                    // Internationalisation. For more info refer to http://datatables.net/manual/i18n
                    "language": {
                        "aria": {
                            "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
                            "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
                        },
                        "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
                        "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
                        "infoEmpty": "No entries found",
                        "infoFiltered": "(filtered1 from _MAX_ total entries)",
                        "lengthMenu": "_MENU_ entries",
                        "search": "Search:",
                        "zeroRecords": "No matching records found"
                    },

                    // Or you can use remote translation file
                    //"language": {
                    //   url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/i18n/Portuguese.json'
                    //},

                    // setup buttons extentension: http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/
                    buttons: [
                        { extend: 'print', className: 'btn dark btn-outline' },
                        { extend: 'pdf', className: 'btn green btn-outline' },
                        { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn purple btn-outline ' }
                    ],

                    // setup responsive extension: http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/
                    responsive: {
                        details: {
                            type: 'column',
                            target: 'tr'
                        }
                    },
                    columnDefs: [ {
                        className: 'control',
                        orderable: false,
                        targets:   0
                    } ],

                    order: [ 1, 'asc' ],

                    // pagination control
                    "lengthMenu": [
                        [5, 10, 15, 20, -1],
                        [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
                    ],
                    // set the initial value
                    "pageLength": 10,
                    "pagingType": 'bootstrap_extended', // pagination type

                    "dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'B>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>", // horizobtal scrollable datatable

                    // Uncomment below line("dom" parameter) to fix the dropdown overflow issue in the datatable cells. The default datatable layout
                    // setup uses scrollable div(table-scrollable) with overflow:auto to enable vertical scroll(see: assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js).
                    // So when dropdowns used the scrollable div should be removed.
                    //"dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'T>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",
                });
            }



            return {

                //main function to initiate the module
                init: function () {

                    if (!jQuery().dataTable) {
                        return;
                    }


                    initTable2();

                }

            };

        }();

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            TableDatatablesResponsive.init();
        });

    });
```

After selecting the date range and calling the ajax function, this is what I get:

[image: after ajax call]

I basically lose the functionality I had before...

I know this might be a stupid post, but as a newbie I'm totally lost and I've been trying to fix it for days.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

for special characters you need to use

```
json_encode(ARRAY, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

may be this will help 
for more information you can check on this link 
[json_encode not working with a html string as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764598/json-encode-not-working-with-a-html-string-as-value)

Comment: Hi, Malkar. Thanks for your reply. The ajax call works, I forgot to post the second image, just edited the post. I'm not sure if my problem is related to css not rendering after ajax call or if I need a callback on my datatable function.

Comment: @Lberteh If that is the case, can you please share your original (i.e. first time) initialization code for dataTable? It seems like those two calls are not matching.

Comment: isn't it the one under var TableDatatablesResponsive = function () {...

I'll be honest, I bought a html template and I don't really know much about js...

Answer (score 0):

i know i might be too late but still try to add this to your css (it worked for me):

```css
th, td { white-space: nowrap; }
```