# Can't access JSON object from MySQL fetch result, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Context, I am doing this PHP project that has function update a product data, 
the situation is the product has an amount of data, after the update, I pack all the data as a JSON object and store into MySQL DB. the reason of packing everything into one JSON object and store as one MySQL row is: in this project, the different product has different attributes, so I think this would be a quick solution for a temporary storing data.

Problem, when I fetch back certain JSON object from MySQL DB, I can not access JSON object, I used JSON decode, but it not works.

here is how I created JSON object

```
$product_INFO = (object)array(
    "ean_number" => "$Static_eanNumber",
    "product_name" => "$productName",
    "product_brand" => "$Brand",
    "product_weight_gr" => "$weight_GR",
    "product_vatrate" => "$vat__Rate",
    "product_supplier" => "$SUPPLIER",
    "product_googleShoppingCategory" => "$GOOGLE_ShoppingCategory",
    "LIGHTSPEED_INFO" => $LIGHTSPEED_product_info_array
);
```

and encode

```
  $Data_in_JSON = json_encode($product_INFO);
```

query

```
  $write_JSON_object = "INSERT INTO editing ( eannumber, json) VALUES ('$Static_eanNumber','$Data_in_JSON')";
```

in mysql database table, the column for JSON is 
Name: json Type: LongText  Collation: utf8mb4_bin

when I fetch from the database, I use this query

```
   $find = "SELECT json FROM editing WHERE eannumber = 10000007 ";
```

and

```
   if (($found->num_rows) == 1) {

    $mysqlJSON = mysqli_fetch_array($found)[0];
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($mysqlJSON);
    echo "</pre>";

}
```

This is the result I see on an HTML page

```
  {"ean_number":"10000007",
  "product_name":"somevalue",
  "product_brand":"Leba",
  "product_weight_gr":"65000",
  "product_vatrate":"0.21",
  "product_supplier":"LebaBenelux",
  "product_googleShoppingCategory":"",
  "LIGHTSPEED_INFO":    [{"product_shop_id":68295980,"product_price":"2854.9533"..........
```

I tried to use JSON decode the MySQL fetch result but it not works, So I cannot access this result by their keys such as "ean_number",

```
   print_r(json_decode($mysqlJSON)->ean_number);
```

I cannot tell where did I made mistake, I create a JSON object in the wrong way? something wrong with MySQL or how I fetch data.

Please help thanks!!!

Comment: Where are you `json_decode`ing the data from the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working for me but you can also change `json_decode($mysqlJSON)->ean_number` to `json_decode($mysqlJSON)` and then access the property you want:

```
$json = '{"ean_number":"10000007",
  "product_name":"somSomething is wrongue",
  "product_brand":"Leba",
  "product_weight_gr":"65000",
  "product_vatrate":"0.21",
  "product_supplier":"LebaBenelux",
         "product_googleShoppingCategory":""}';


$decoded = json_decode($json);

echo $decoded->ean_number;
```

Comment: may I ask you about encode and decode the text contains HTML tags, it is the same application, but I have the problem that if the text I encoding and decoding contains HTML tags, I cannot decode them back. I tried some solutions I found from PHP.net, not works. I appreciate if you could help me out, thank you very much

Comment: @LevittShanHe maybe this will help you? [json-encode-not-working-with-a-html-string-as-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764598/json-encode-not-working-with-a-html-string-as-value)