# HTML in JSON, use utf8_encode but kills some characters?

Tags: php, ajax, json

To make it short I am receiving HTML through some json, in an ajax jquery call. `response.html`

Now for this html, after `file_get_contents()` and some filters, I am wrapping it with `utf8_encode()` to make it able to transfer with JSON and not make some of the syntax break the JSON. I found out that I should do this, thanks to [Putting HTML in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492916/putting-html-in-json)

It all works fine until I have the danish, swedish characters: öäå

It makes these: `Ã¶Ã¤Ã¥` . How can I fix this? Is there another way to escape the html string?

My Response header is utf-8.

[image]

Comment: you might be utf8-encoding, but you still need to tell the client-side that you're actually SENDING utf-8. Otherwise it's free to interpret it as being whatever the client browser is using, e.g. iso8859. Getting `Ã` like you are is a clear symptom of an incorrect charset being used in the client.

Comment: `uft-8` != `utf-8`... Dyslexic moment?

Comment: updated, the issue remains

Answer (score 1):

The `utf8_encode()` function should only be used for ISO-8859-1 data.

If you already have UTF-8 encoded data, you will see the following transformation:

```
c3b6 c3a4 c3a5             (öäå)

c383c2b6 c383c2a4 c383c2a5 (Ã¶Ã¤Ã¥)
```

Either you have to make sure the read data is ISO-8859-1 or don't apply `utf8_encode()`.